# RewriteRule where Group may be there or may be not

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Not getting proper words for the title and the question, but practically you will understand the question.

I have **`.htaccess`** file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([A-Za-z0-9]+={0,2})&quiz=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&refer=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^(quiz)\.php$ /college/$1/%1/%2/%3 [QSD,R=302,L]

RewriteRule    ^quiz/?$    quiz.php    [L]
RewriteRule ^quiz/([A-Za-z0-9]+={0,2})/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ quiz.php?user=$1&quiz=$2&refer=$3    [L]
```

Now, when I request:`http://localhost/college/quiz.php?user=MTA&quiz=238&refer=jitu`,

it changes to `http://localhost/college/quiz/MTA/238/jitu`.

**This is the same result as expected**

## BUT

When I request:`http://localhost/college/quiz.php?user=MTA&quiz=238`, it **remains same**. ie: **`http://localhost/college/quiz.php?user=MTA&quiz=238`**. My ***expectations*** are:

> `http://localhost/college/quiz/MTA/238`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match when only the first two URL parameters are provided you need to make the 3rd URL parameter *optional*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([A-Za-z0-9]+={0,2})&quiz=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(?:&refer=([A-Za-z0-9-]+))?
```

The `?:` prefix on the 3rd *optional* group makes it non-capturing, this is so that it doesn't interfere with the `%3` backreference - which remains as the *value* of the `refer` URL parameter, which will simply be empty when the `refer` URL parameter is omitted.

This will, however, result in `/college/quiz/MTA/238/` (with a trailing slash), not `/college/quiz/MTA/238` - as in your example. But this will ensure that it will still match the later rewrite. However, you will need to change the corresponding matching group in the rewrite to match 0 or more characters (ie. `*` quantifier), not 1 or more (ie. `+`) as it is currently. ie. change `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$` to `([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/?$`.

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/([A-Za-z0-9]+={0,2})/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/?$ quiz.php?user=$1&quiz=$2&refer=$3    [L]
```

Comment: Is this that, `.htaccess` does not work when  groups are shuffled? Eg: `http://localhost/college/quiz.php?quiz=238&user=MTA`, just want to know, if in future the group sequence are changed

Comment: `.htaccess`, or specifically mod_rewrite, is all about _pattern matching_, there is no concept of individual URL parameters except for how you construct the regular expression. So, the above works for the URL given in your question. If the URL parameters could be in any order then you would need to construct multiple rules to handle this. However, the order of path segments in your actual URL `/quiz/MTA/238/jitu` cannot be in any order - this should not change. So, really the URL parameter order should never really change either.

Comment: The only real reason to implement the redirect is if you are changing an existing URL structure and the old URLs (with parameters) have been indexed by search engines or backlinked from external sites. So, if you find there has been an inconsistent URL structure in the past then you will need multiple rules to correct this. However, going forward, the URL parameter is not normally an issue?